# Need to get part from string in php with regex or something else

Tags: php, regex, json, string

I got this string returned when I access http://www.draugiem.lv/bkventspils/js/fans?count=0

```
D.w({"container":"pagescontainer","width":240,"page":{"name":"BK Ventspils","about":"Basketbola Klubs \"Ventspils\"","url":"http:\/\/www.draugiem.lv\/bkventspils","image":"http:\/\/i7.ifrype.com\/business\/001\/547\/v1319550676\/i_13001547.jpg","totalfans":"557"},"fans":[]});
```

I need to get "totalfans" count from this string in php. I tried to do it with file_get_contents and then json_decode like I usually would do but it's not working with this string. What I'm doing wrong here? Probably there is a regex to get this part, bu I don't understand regex, so if you do please help me.

Comment: The site seems to return JS code rather than actual JSON. So JSON decode function will fail.

Comment: Youre right, then I guess I can use some regex instead to get this part I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions to your problem.

**1. JSON:**
Simply get rid of the `D.w(` at the beginning and the `);` at the end and you end up with a string containing valid JSON.

**2. RegEx:** A search for the pattern `"totalfans":"(\d+)"` should do the trick.